# How to get sending message status from Kannel SMS server,.?

Tags: php, kannel

I'm using Kannel sms server for sending sms.
How to get sending message status (Sent, pending or failed) from kannel,.?
I also using PHP for it's programming language.

Answer (score 3):

In the [chapter 9](http://www.kannel.org/download/1.5.0/userguide-1.5.0/userguide.html#DELIVERY-REPORTS) of [Kannel User's Guide](http://www.kannel.org/download/1.5.0/userguide-1.5.0/userguide.html) you can find an explanation of how to do this, basically you set a dlr-url and a dlr-mask to direct kannel which kind of notifications to send you and on which urls.